# Need help in understanding discrete and active protection circuits

Tags: diodes, protection, circuit-protection

[image]

[Reference](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva862a/slva862a.pdf?ts=1681283665717)

I'd appreciate if someone could break these circuits down and help me understand what portion does what.

For Fig 1

1. Does the capacitor placed just after the Zener diode (input side) serve as a soft start capacitance perhaps to limit inrush current?
2. Zener diode in parallel with capacitor (whose discharge is controlled with the help of the resistor in parallel to it.) Why is the capacitor placed there? Unlike the capacitor placed in parallel with load which can act as an hold up capacitance.
3. What exactly are the comparators doing? It seems like some sort of voltage divider configuration which is then fed to the inverting terminals of both the comparators. Is this in the inverting configuration with V(ref) as some fraction of V(in)?
4. Why is the gate of the NMOS is connected to the capacitor part as well as collector of the BJT? What is the BJT doing here? Is it switching based on the comparator output?
5. The body diode of enhancement type pmos is for protection against reverse current?

6.The Gate of PMOS, enable line to base of bjt and the output of comparator how are these working?

I need help with the active protection circuit as well.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: No, I have little to no experience with the same. This was a part of the datasheet I'm going through, so I just needed clarification before going ahead.

Comment: @Harkirat Can you provide the references to where you got the images from?

Comment: @VoltageSpike added, you can find the same on Pg 3

Comment: OK, a couple of comments.  These diagrams are illustrations of circuits the efuse replaces.  
The first one disables the pass element if the voltage is out of range, the second one disables the pass element if the current is too high.  Pass element = Pchan FET in those diagrams.

The capacitor you mentioned will slow the gate turn on/off, but is only a crude soft-start mechanism.

Comment: The body diode is an intrinsic property of FETs.  In most applications, this should not be forward biased.  The diagram seems to indicate that these are discrete diodes added in addition to the FETs (so, not body diodes).

Comment: Yeah the body diode only comes into play once the FET is OFF. To prevent reverse current if any, right?

Comment: The BJT turns ON or OFF the pass element.  If the BJT is biased on, then the gate of the FET will be pulled low, thus enabling it.

Comment: Irrespective of the titles of each diagram, they both use discrete components and they both use active components. Maybe you or I are getting confused by your question title?

Comment: My best recommendation to understand a circuit is to simulate it, probe everything, try changing things and see what it affects to build your own understanding. There are several free circuit simulators out there.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, adding to it, protection circuits too, are classified into two types active & discrete. According to the reference provided, active current protection can respond faster to overcurrent faults and provides better current limit accuracies.

Comment: The word "classified" does not appear in the document you linked. The word "type" is used three times and appears to have a usage unrelated to what you are talking about.

Comment: Apologies for my casual denotations.